# Using # define between two C # projects

Tags: c#, .net, c-preprocessor, using-directives

Under one Solution two projects, one Main, second UnitTestMain.

From project UnitTestMain need to call a method and pass somehow `#define TEST` to be processed.

Project UnitTestMain:

```
#define TEST
using System;
namespace UnitTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest
    {
        private Calculate calc = new Calculate();

        [TestMethod]
        public void Test()
        {
            calc.test());

        }
    }
}
```

Project Main

```
public bool test()
        {
            bool ok;
#if TEST
            ok = true;
#else
            ok = false;
#endif
        }
```

Method test return: false. But need true.

Comment: Really? How can you suppose that your question will be answered if _entire site_ is in English?

Comment: as you can not understand the meaning of "Yeda aahe tu"...we can not understand Использование #define между двумя C# проектами

Comment: @AlmaDo: it *can*, but it's not correct, as site is in english: so you have less persons that understand what you asking for and may be learn from the answers, and less probability to be answered.

Comment: My English is very bad, but i redid

Comment: i See summary listing in russion... now this page is english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to the project properties you compile and :

[image]

define your TEST inside that field. The field is *Conditional compilation symbols*.

Comment: would have been funny if your answer was in (looks like italian?) ;)

Comment: Its Properties in TEST project, hey will only work on one project. If I list them in another project, the test will be available in any case.

Comment: Conditional compilation symbols it is also that of #define.

Comment: @ViktorKudlai: you can define you custom build configuration: no RELEASE, no DEBUG, where you specify conditinal compiation symbols for every project. One time saved it, you can switch build configuration from the *solution* and it will apply corresponding property sets for every project it contains.

Comment: @slashmais: yes, unfortunately company bought me italian version of VS, would prefer english one

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that the configuration saved for a separate build